# How to insert data into mysql database using AJAX (without refreshing whole page)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 


 function ajaxcall()
 {



    var namejs=document.getElementById("namejs").value;
    var emailjs=document.getElementById("emailjs").value;
    var passjs=document.getElementById("passjs").value;
    var selected_gender=document.getElementById("selected_gender").value;
    var div_id=document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML;


    var xmlhttp=new new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","response_insert.php?name="+namejs+"&email="+emailjs+"&password="+passjs+"&gender="+selected_gender);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    div_id=xmlhttp.responseText();


 }
</script>




//Here  my response_php page  code written below


<?php

  include "insert.php";
  extract($_REQUEST);

  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("demo");
   $name=$_GET["name"];
   $email=$_GET["email"];
   $password=$_GET["password"];
   $gender=$_GET["gender"];

 
   
   


   mysql_query("insert into tbl (name,email,password,gender) value ('$name','$email','$password','$gender')") or die("Data not inserted");
   echo "Inserted Successfully";


  

?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Insert using Ajax,Jquery,Php,MySql</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="insert.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <style type="text/css">
  .form-control
  {
   width: 300px;
  }
  .s
  {
   width: 100px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
    
    <form  role="form" >
     <div class="form-group">
      <strong>Name</strong>
      <input type="text" id="namejs" class="form-control" name="">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <strong>Email</strong>
      <input type="text" id="emailjs" class="form-control" name="">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <strong>Password</strong>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passjs" name="">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <strong>Gender</strong>
       <select class="form-control s" id="selected_gender">
        <option>Male</option>
        <option>Female</option>
       </select>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <button type="button" id="submitjs" onclick="ajaxcall()" class="btn btn-success">INSERT
       </button>
      </div>

     
    </form>
   </div>

   <div id="div_id">
    
   </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I want to insert data into MySql  database without refreshing the whole page...here is my code..

i have written response_insert.php page's  code below javascript code..........
what is problem is there....
How can i do that using Ajax and javascript and php

please give the answer.......................................................................

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: honestly just use jquery for your ajax its so much less hassle

Comment: Agree with @TheCodesee JQuery / AJAX is extremely straight forward and will be quickest way of doing this

Comment: More tabs! More space!

Comment: Your code will never work in PHP 7 because you're using mysql_* functions, which are obsolete and which have been removed.  Even if they were still present your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Also ```extract($_REQUEST);``` is a REALLY REALLY BAD idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'response_insert.php',
     type: 'get',
     data: {
           name: namejs,
           email: emailjs,
           password: passjs,
           gender: selected_gender
     }
     success: function(response){
           //do stuff
      },
     error: function(error){ console.log(error.responseText);}

});
```

**UPDATE:**
First of all when you are going to insert data you should use *POST*. See differences between get and post [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp). So your ajax would look like that:

```
 $.ajax({
         url: 'response_insert.php',
         type: 'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
               name: namejs,
               email: emailjs,
               password: passjs,
               gender: selected_gender
         }
         success: function(response){
               console.log(response); //here is response from your php 
          },
         error: function(error){ console.log(error.responseText);}

    });
```

**response_insert.php**

```
    <?php

            include "insert.php";

            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");

            $name=$_POST["name"];
            $email=$_POST["email"];
            $password=$_POST["password"];
            $gender=$_POST["gender"];






                if(mysqli_query("insert into tbl (name,email,password,gender) values ('$name','$email','$password','$gender')"){     echo "inserted successfully"; }
else{ echo mysqli_error($con);}



    ?>
```

Comment: not getting output can you send me complete code ????with PHP and JQUERY AJAX code please

Comment: is data being inserted into database?

Comment: take a look I made my answer more datailed

Comment: whats problem??

Comment: Insertion problem no data  inserted

Comment: did you changed your sql query? You had in your question 'value' and you should to have 'values'

Comment: look, I changed my answer again. Now in your response came out error text and write down how it does look like

Comment: are you checking ajax response?

Comment: in MySql Database the datatype of Gender is set to VARCHAR is it ok ??

Comment: There is no response from AJAX

Comment: I have added the following in Head tag is there any need of library 
                                                                                                     
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: and now works?? I assumed that you had already imported jquery

Comment: I have added the following in Head tag is there any need of library <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/…

Comment: no. Write your javascript trace if there is some error

Comment: No there  is no error text...but data is not inserted into database

Answer (score 0):

I would used [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for your AJAX call.

```
 function ajaxcall() {
    var namejs = $("#namejs").val();
    var emailjs = $("#emailjs").val();
    var password = $("#passjs").val();
    var selected_gender = $("#selected_gender").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'response_insert.php',
      dataType: json,
      data: {
       name: namejs,
       email: emailjs,
       password: passjs,
       gender: selected_gender
      },
      success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
      }
    });
}
```

Or alternatively if you don't want to use JSON you can mix some jQuery with pure JavaScript:

```
 function ajaxcall() {
    var namejs = $("#namejs").val();
    var emailjs = $("#emailjs").val();
    var password = $("#passjs").val();
    var selected_gender = $("#selected_gender").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'response_insert.php',
      data: "name=" + namejs + "&email=" + emailjs + "&password=" + passjs + "&gender=" + selected_gender,
      success: function(response) {
          alert(response);
      }
    });
}
```

And your response_insert.php:

```
<?php
function clean_data($data){   // sanitizes inputs
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

// need to decode JSON, if you don't use JSON just pass the $_POST to clean_data()
$name_dirty = json_decode($_POST['name']);
$email_dirty = json_decode($_POST['email']);
$password_dirty = json_decode($_POST['password']);
$gender_dirty = json_decode($_POST['gender']);

// takes parameters from AJAX call and passes them to clean_data() for sanitization
$name = clean_data($name_dirty);
$email = clean_data($email_dirty);
$password = clean_data($password_dirty);
$gender = clean_data($gender_dirty);

// MySQL portion
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$query = "INSERT INTO database.tbl (name,email,password,gender) VALUES ('$name','$email','$password','$gender')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if($result) {
    echo $result; // or whatever you want
} else {
    "Something went wrong."
}

?>
```

Comment: Let me check this one

Comment: Make sure you close the string in the `url: 'response_insert.php'` I didn't have the close quote when I originally answered

Comment: Still not working.......hello  there is "insert into database.tbl" or "insert into tbl" ?????????/